# How can the Mail iOS application alerting for new mail while it is NOT running

Tags: ios, background, push-notification

I tried to send an email to my own account using a laptop.
On my iPad the Mail application is completely out of memory, not in background... and magically still show the badge for the new mail just sent.

Does anyone have the idea on how this is programmatically implemented?

Answer (score 3):

Quick response : Apple can do whatever they want.

Long response : the Mail app *is* running. You can use apps like iStat that will list you all the running processes. The **MobileMail** process is always running, whatever I do. If I kill the Mail app in the multitasking bar, it will be in fact killed, but will be relaunched immediately. You obviously can't do that as a 3rd party developer. Apple can do whatever they want.

And that's the case with old devices on pre-multitasking OS/ability the MobileMail process is always running.

Answer (score 0):

It uses the iOS notification system, which doesn't require the application to be running. [See Apples tutorial for the nitty gritty](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html).

Comment: It cannot be. Each mail server should be aware of the "Push Notification" architecture and should implement it, but this is unlikely.

Comment: I guess that the device perform some kind of "pull" approach to check for new mail...

Comment: Mail pulls mail, it doesn't get pushed. (Except perhaps for MobileMe and Yahoo! Mail, but it still doesn't use push notifications — the emails are downloaded even when Mail is in the background, you can't do such a thing with push notifications.)

Comment: The question was more focused on the badges, which is notification system, I was assuming that Mail was provided as a general example. No application *needs* to be running to receive badges, Mail is an edge case of Apple allowing a background task that checks on a repeat basis.