# How does the mail application on iOS work?

Tags: ios, email, imap

I understand from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204771/how-can-the-mail-ios-application-alerting-for-new-mail-while-it-is-not-running) that the system Mail application never gets "killed" and that it is always running to fetch emails. I also gather that 3rd party applications are not fortunate enough to do the same.

Well, then how do email applications like [spark](https://sparkmailapp.com/) manage to fetch new emails even when they are inactive?

Answer (score 1):

In iOS7 Apple exposed API for Multitasking in background. 
More about that in [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).
But, the idea is that you can download small chunks of data in background, while your app is not active.

Comment: If my understanding is correct, for background fetch iOS decides when to call the fetch. Mail apps seem to deliver notifications as soon as a new mail is received. Even when they have not been launched. How does that work?

Comment: @HellsGuardian oh, that is just push notifications. Read more about it here:
https://developer.apple.com/notifications/

Comment: Oh that's cool. So the actual fetching of content sort of happens on the server(provider) and when there is a new data(email), it sends a notification to the user?

Comment: @HellsGuardian exactly.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll try to sum things up for clarity. Please bear with me. So the application fetches content from the mail server only when it is in the foreground. It receives notifications from the provider when it is in the suspended state prompting the user to open the app which triggers a fetch to load the content?

Comment: @HellsGuardian right, it triggers user to open the app, but alongside with that it contains some data already, like title and few lines of body etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121831/discussion-between-hells-guardian-and-pavel-gatilov).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [background fetch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) (search for `background fetch`), which allows fetching small amount of contents opportunistically when the app is in background.

If you know when new contents are available, remote push notification is a more reliable option. But it is not the case for emails.

Comment: Background fetch does not guarantee a fetch in the specified time interval. iOS decides when to call the fetch. But, mail applications deliver notifications almost instantaneously. How does that happen?

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that can happen instantly, haven't seen that on my device

Comment: Well, yes. It may take a while at times but it's there always. Push notifications apparently do the job!